# Scalar product with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

How do I get the values of the parameters in this equation?

$\langle x,y\rangle = x_1y_1-2x_1y_2+ax_2y_1+bx_2y_2$

I do know that this equation shows a scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but how do I get a and b? Would it be something like a linear system?

Comment: You have to use the properties of a scalar product, for example, the one that says it's symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, using the properties of a scalar product, you have:

1. $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle y,x\rangle$ implies that $a=-2$.
2. $\langle x,x\rangle \ge 0$ implies that $b\ge4$.
3. Since $\langle x,x\rangle = 0$ has to imply that $x=0$, it is necessary that $b>4$.

For points 2 and 3, note that $\langle x,x\rangle = (x_1-2x_2)^2+(b-4)x_2^2$

Comment: If $b$ is, say, $17$, and $\langle\,x,x\,\rangle=0$, doesn't that still imply $x=0$?

Comment: You are right. In fact, for $b=4$ it would not be an inner product, but a semi-inner product. I have edited my answer.

By the way, are all $b>4$ possible? Or am I missing anything else?

Comment: You're fine with any $b>4$.